# Incorrect width for UILabel with autolayout and conditional constraints

Tags: ios, uilabel, autolayout

I have a custom UITableViewCell with a UIImageView and a UILabel (which can be multi-lined). This is all setup in IB, but for simplicity these are the autolayout constraints:

```
|-15-[imageView(80.0)]-[label]-|
|-15@500-[label]-|
V:|-[imageView(80.0)]
V:|-[label]
```

The idea is that if the UIImageView outlet is nil, then the label stretches to the leading edge. I am not sure if I am using constraints in the correct way to do this, but it seems to work fine.

This is my problem: in some cases the UILabel ends up with a height greater than it needs. For example, autolayout calculates that the UILabel will contain two lines of text, taking the UIImageView into consideration, but then if the UIImageView is not there the text actually fits on a single line.

I read this very good article [Advanced Auto Layout Toolbox](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox.html) which helped a lot. It seems that the problem concerns the preferredMaxLayoutWidth on the UILabel. I followed the suggestion to try this on the UITableViewCell:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    myLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = myLabel.frame.size.width;
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

However, this has not solved the problem. Some debugging has demonstrated that even after the first call to `[super layoutSubviews]` the `myLabel.frame.size.width` always takes the UIImageView into consideration. However, by the time it is displayed the UIImageView is missing and the UILabel is the full width as expected (but too high).

I hope my explanation makes sense. I would have posted some pictures to make it simpler, but it seems I am not able to do so as a newbie to stackoverflow.com! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why don't you always have an image view?  If there's no image, its frame would be CGRectZero, and you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: @AaronBrager I think I may have misunderstood your suggestion. I tried removing the second constraint above, and changing the UIImageView width constraint to <=80. However, the labels now don't stretch to the left-hand margin when no image is set.